# ERROR Duplicate case value in my c++ program. Though I cannot change anything

Tags: c++, duplicates, switch-statement, case

I tried to write a program that can help me find trigonometric values of a given angle. Below is the program,

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

void convert(char type);

int main()
{
    char ch;


    cout<<"Enter what angle value u want to calculate: 'c' for cos, 's' for sine and 't' for tan: ",cin>>ch;

    convert(ch);

    return 0;
}

void convert(char type)
{
    float angle;
    double num;
    switch (type)
    {
        case 'C' || 'c':
            cout<<"Enter angle value to calculate cos equivalent: ",cin>>angle;
            num = cos(angle);
            break;
        case 's' || 'S':
            cout<<"Enter angle value to calculate sin equivalent: ",cin>>angle;
            num = sin(angle);
            break;
        case 'T' || 't':
            cout<<"Enter angle value to calculate tan equivalent: ",cin>>angle;
            num = tan(angle);
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"\n\nInvalid Character\n";
    }
}
```

But the code gives me error as

> [Error] duplicate case value

Someone please help me understand the logic behind this error and an alternate solution for this problem.

Regards,

Comment: All of your `case` statements are equivalent to `case true:` - which makes me wonder who taught you that you can write them like that?

Comment: Why do you ask for help if you can't change anything?  'A'||'B' is equivalent to (65 || 66) as ascii, which is (true || true) which is just "true".  So yes, you have duplicate case statements since every case handles true.

Answer (score 5):

If you really can't change anything then you are stuck, but the correct code is

```
case 'C': case 'c':
```

etc. etc.

You should understand that `||` is an operator with a precise meaning, it doesn't mean the same as 'or' in the English language. So

```
case 'C' || 'c':
```

does not mean 'case C or c'. It means calculate the value of `'C' || 'c'` and use that value for the case statement.

Comment: Your  clue worked for me.

    case 'C':
    case 'c':
             statements......;

Thanks for help

Comment: _"`case 'C' || 'c':` does not mean 'case C or c'"_ It does. But, that is not what the OP wants to do, which is 'case C or case c`.

Answer (score 1):

Either make the input `ch` of  same case(all lower or upper) as

```
if(ch >='A' && ch <= 'Z')
ch=tolower(ch);
switch(ch) {
 /** **/
}
```

OR

```
case  'C' :
case  'c' :
        cout<<"Enter angle value to calculate cos equivalent: ",cin>>angle;
        num = cos(angle);
```